# Dynamic sum of one column based on NA values of another column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dynamic, group-by, sum, rolling-computation

I've got an ordered dataframe, df. It's grouped by 'ID' and ordered by 'order'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A','A', 'B','B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'],
     'order': [1,3,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,19,25,8,10,15,17,20,25,29,31],
     'col1': [1,2,np.nan, 1,2,3,4,5, np.nan, np.nan,6,7,8,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10,11,12,np.nan,13],
     'col2': [1,5,6,np.nan,1,2,3,np.nan,2,3,np.nan,np.nan,3,1,5,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,2,3, np.nan,np.nan],
     }
)
```

In each ID group, I would need to sum col1 for those rows that have col2 as NA. The sum includes the value of col1 for which the next value of col2 exists:

I prefer a vecterised solution to make it fast, but it could be difficult.
i need to use this in a groupby (as col1_dynamic_sum should be grouped by ID)

What i have done so far, is define a function that helps count the number of previous consecutive NAs in the row:

```
def count_prev_consec_na(input_col):
    """
    This function takes a dataframe Series (column) and outputs the number of consecutive misisng values in previous rows
    """    
    try:
        a1 = input_col.isna() + 0 ## missing
        a2 = ~input_col.isna() + 0  ## not missing
        b1 = a1.shift().fillna(0) ## prev missing
        d = a1.cumsum()
        e = b1*a2
        f = d*e
        g = f.replace(0, np.nan)
        h=g.ffill()
        h = h.fillna(0)
        i = h.shift()
        result = h-i
        result = result.fillna(0)

        return (result)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
        return None
```

I think one solution is to use this to get a dynamic number of rows that needs to be rolled back for sum:

```
df['roll_back_count'] = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index = False).col2.transform(count_prev_consec_na)

ID  order   col1    col2    roll_back_count
A   1       1.0     1.0         0.0
A   3       2.0     5.0         0.0
A   4       NaN     6.0         0.0
A   6       1.0     NaN         0.0  
A   7       2.0     1.0         1.0    ## I want to sum col1 of order 6 and 7 and remove order 6 row
A   9       3.0     2.0         0.0
A   11      4.0     3.0         0.0
A   12      5.0     NaN         0.0
A   13      NaN     2.0         1.0   ## I want to sum col1 of order 12 and 13 and remove order 12 row
A   14      NaN     3.0         0.0
A   15      6.0     NaN         0.0
A   16      7.0     NaN         0.0
A   19      8.0     3.0         2.0   ## I want to sum col1 of order 15,16,19 and remove order 15 and 16 rows
A   25      9.0     1.0         0.0
B   8       NaN     5.0         0.0
B   10      NaN     NaN         0.0
B   15      NaN     NaN         0.0
B   17      10.0    NaN         0.0   ## I want to sum col1 of order 10,15,17,20 and remove order 10,15,17 rows
B   20      11.0    2.0         3.0
B   25      12.0    3.0         0.0
B   29      NaN     NaN         0.0
B   31      13.0    NaN         0.0
```

this is my desired output:

```
desired_output:

    ID  order   col1_dynamic_sum    col2
    A   1       1.0                 1
    A   3       2.0                 5
    A   4       NaN                 6
    A   7       3.0                 1
    A   9       3.0                 2
    A   11      4.0                 3
    A   13      5.0                 2
    B   14      NaN                 3
    B   19      21.0                3
    B   25      9.0                 1
    B   8       NaN                 5
    B   20      21.0                2
    B   25      12.0                3
```

note: the sums should ignore NAs
again, i prefer vecterised solution, but it might not be possible due to the rolling effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I think I found a solution that doesn't involve rolling at all!
I created a new grouping ID based on NA values of the col2, using the index of rows that don't have any values. I would then use this grouping ID to aggregate!

```
def create_na_group(rollback_col):
    a = ~rollback_col.isna() + 0
    b = a.replace(0, np.nan)
    c = rollback_col.index
    d = c*b
    d = d.bfill()
    return(d)

df['na_group'] = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index = False).col2.transform(create_na_group)

df = df.loc[~df.na_group.isna()]
desired_output = df.groupby(['ID','na_group'], as_index=False).agg(
      order = ('order', 'last')
    , col1_dyn_sum = ('col1', sum)
    , col2 = ('col2', sum)
)
```

I just have to find a way to make sure NaN don't become 0, like in rows 2,7 and 10.

```
    ID  na_group    order   col1_dyn_sum    col2
0   A       0.0     1       1.0             1.0
1   A       1.0     3       2.0             5.0
2   A       2.0     4       0.0             6.0
3   A       4.0     7       3.0             1.0
4   A       5.0     9       3.0             2.0
5   A       6.0     11      4.0             3.0
6   A       8.0     13      5.0             2.0
7   A       9.0     14      0.0             3.0
8   A       12.0    19      21.0            3.0
9   A       13.0    25      9.0             1.0
10  B       14.0    8       0.0             5.0
11  B       18.0    20      21.0            2.0
12  B       19.0    25      12.0            3.0
```

I'll just creat two separate sum columns with lamba x: x.sum(skipna = False) and lamba x: x.sum(skipna = True) and then if the skipna = True sum column is 0 and skipna = False sum column is NA then I'll leave the final sum as NA, otherwise, I use the skipna = True sum column as the final desired output.